# Awake sleeping detached java process

Tags: java, linux, process, cpu, scheduling

I wrote a Java program, which analyses other programs. The execution may take very long (= days). Now (after three days), I have the problem, that my program / process is sleeping (S). It still has allocated 50% of the memory and sometimes it prints new output, but *top* shows must of the time 0% CPU.

I used *jstack* to be sure, that there are still runnable threads. Hence, it seems not to be a deadlock problem. I do not know, why the process does not get more cpu time. I chanced the *niceness* of the java process from 0 to -10, but nothing happends.

More details:
The process runs on a linux server: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS.
I started my process with *screen*. So, I do not have to be logged in all the time.

```
screen -S analyse ant myParameters
```

The server has almost nothing to do.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should add some logging info to your program to be shure that the threads are still working.

Comment: Details provided by you is not sufficient .Please provide some code snippet of your program.

Comment: Thanks for your relpies. I am sure, that the threads are still working, because *jstack* shows, that they are runnable and from time to time the program prints new console output.

Answer (score 0):

Start your program in debug mode.  Then you can attach to it with any Java debugger and inspect what it is doing.